# Laravel Scout with Meilisearch returns results for some models and not others

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am trying to use laravel scout with meilisearch to return results from an index for products.
It doesn't work for this model however it does for my user model.

I have gone through both to try and find differences that would be causing this and can't seem to find out what the issue is.

when I run

```
return \App\Models\Product\Product::search('iphone')->raw();
```

I get the raw results from the meilisearch index.

however when i run

```
return \App\Models\Product\Product::search('iphone')->get();
```

no results show.

more information:
meilisearch/meilisearch-php : 1.4.1
laravel/scout: 10.5.1

when using `getKey` and `getScoutKey` the correct `_id` key name is returned (it is the same on the User model where search is working

there are no filtered out results or related models

Product Model

```
    protected $primaryKey = self::ID;

    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        $searchable                         = [];
        $searchable[self::ID]               = $this->getAttribute(self::ID);
        $searchable[self::NAME]             = $this->getAttribute(self::NAME);
        $searchable[self::SLUG]             = $this->getAttribute(self::SLUG);
        $searchable[self::MODEL_NAME]       = $this->getAttribute(self::MODEL_NAME);
        $searchable[self::MODEL_SUB]        = $this->getAttribute(self::MODEL_SUB);
        $searchable[self::MODEL_GENERATION] = $this->getAttribute(self::MODEL_GENERATION);
        $searchable[self::MODEL_SIZE]       = $this->getAttribute(self::MODEL_SIZE);
        $searchable[self::MODEL_EXTRA]      = $this->getAttribute(self::MODEL_EXTRA);
        $searchable[self::BRAND_NAME]       = ($this->brand) ? $this->brand->name : 'unknown';
        $searchable[self::DESCRIPTION]      = $this->getAttribute(self::DESCRIPTION);

        return $searchable;
    }
```

Anyone have any idea's on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On another project that accesses the same meilisearch instance and databases, which is on Laravel 8 where the results were being returned using get(), rather than the project where this was failing a Laravel 10 project.

Downgrading the followin packages to match the Laravel 8 project fixed the issue, obviously this is not long term as a solution but got me going again on the feature where this was required.

```
meilisearch/meilisearch-php: 1.4.1 downgraded to ^0.24.2
laravel/scout: 10.5.1 downgraded to ^9.4
```